Format of the circom output files - is it documented?
In the circom documentation, I found file formats for their input files, but I cannot find documentation format for their json exported output file.
I ran the following circom commands till the end of Phase 1
- snarkjs powersoftau new bn128 3 pot3_0.ptau -v

- snarkjs powersoftau contribute pot3_0.ptau pot3_1.ptau

- snarkjs powersoftau prepare phase2 pot3_1.ptau pot3ph1.ptau

This is end of Phase 1.
I exported this to a JSON format
snarkjs ptej pot3ph1.ptau pot3ph1.json

Now my pot3ph1.json has various entries which I am confused about
This is one of the entries
 "tauG1": [
  "19251647757787308156787743079029887954678750029819827393622431040979082323348",
  "16995615570386218649393438807906035411544964728205408874350435668005782929797",
  "11739844020453067775262004353631423573598590005762765636476362862997313373685",
  "3183136198242885847864693287447448131389141133959069812653229921195621371156",
  "10494714696609538664504890640193999656960626351947737474469035003583744804022",
  "14414904713013921861012777781112718065712931689121497750347014494581792324300",
  "4926884863765166084861316831423744481803840944396449622145190227628666599953",
  "14735084288381257536040482865429151508084350567748826707588710711492268719809",
  "13738771809795149000381704185403277858165991078185376778724546827748952628176",
  "1830096545796532715862600099716454800122506493286209386525834245544096867171",
  "14324389469398762821103045886342451521490001976198397530287288030965773746846",
  "6918147581599398122171885970865691813996451882738781803627345490998323929448",
  "13596990979001787063254096742585281606929390975862735066095138026399861972193",
  "18908840736218986199052735158730185940802865102578068839266225809694722333008",
  "14071721851576309185227219103979595574546906005919834763691492415608303066094"
 ],

These are 15 different elements for tauG1. Each power of tau would be an elliptic curve point - I don't understand how I ended up with 15 entries when the first command I had run, I had specified 3.
Each power of tau multiplied by G1 (generator) would be an elliptic curve point - each point is represented by x & y - i.e 2 numbers. So how did I end up with an odd number(15) elements?
